# Set default value on page load using Jquery (I am using multiselect plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple requirement however I am using multiselect plugin hence i am not able to debug. Please help

I am using multiselect dropdown plugin - http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

This is my html:

```
<select id="example2" name="example"   multiple="multiple" class="multiselect" onclick="filterLocation();">

            <option id="aa" value="Ready">Ready</option>
            <option id="bb" value="Overdue" >Overdue</option>
            <option id="cc" value="Pending" >Pending</option>
            <option id="dd" value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>]

This is my javascript:

    j$(document).ready(function() {

        j$("select.multiselect").multiSelect();

        j$("#example2").val("Pending");
     });
```

I want to set the value "Pending" when i load the page. However its not visible in the UI. I tried below options to set the value using jquery but its not working :(

```
j$('#example2').find('option[value="Pending"]').attr(selected, selected);
document.getElementById('bb').selected= true;
document.getElementById('bb').checked= true;
```

Could you please suggest me why its not checking/selecting the value while using plugin?

Please see the screenshot attached..

Thanks a lot. Any suggestion is highly appreciated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCJcF.jpg

Comment: Did you try http://api.jquery.com/prop/ ? `$('#bb').prop('selected',true)`

Comment: Yeah.. i tried this as well.. Looks like i need to change something in plugin. But dont know exactly what to do :(

Comment: Can somebody help with this? Thanks in Advance.. I could not find anything wrong in plugin as well

Comment: In demo https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/tree/master/demos , there is demo for preselected. This way you can select option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can select options

**HTML :**

```
        <select multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
        <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
        <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
        </select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('select').find('option[value="option3"]').attr("selected", "selected");
$('select').find('option[value="option4"]').attr("selected", "selected");


$("select").multiselect();
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. But this option is not defined in the plugin. I used another multiselect plugin and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do your selection in the `create` lifecycle event this plugin exposes.

```
$("#multiselect").multiselect({
    create: function(event, ui){
       // do your selection here
    }
});
```

Alternativley, instead of selecting with the html attribute, you might be able to use the multiselect `option` method. From the docs (after it's initialized) do something like this:

```
$("#multiselect").multiselect("option", "Pending");
```

Comment: Hi Thedeeno, I tried it now. Its not doing.. even the documentations does not say how to preselect the value. Thanks